# How to know which private key use to decipher when there is more than one in the keystore

Tags: java, keystore, public-key-encryption, jks

I have a system that receives requests encoded with 2 different public keys and which I have to decipher with the respective private keys that I have in the Java keystore.

How can I know which one of the private keys in my JKS I should use to decipher? Preferably better than test-and-fail till I find the correct key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of encryption standards (like [CMS](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652.txt), [XML Encrpyption](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/), [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/)...) require the inclusion of an unambiguous way to determine the public key used to encrypt. It could be a reference to the public key (i.e. a hash) or a certificate. With this indication it is possible to select the correct private key.

Unfortunately if the system you are using does not provide that kind of indication I don't think there is no other way than try-and-fail.

Comment: And how you could know if a private key corresponds to a determinated public key?

Comment: It depends on the type of key. But for RSA which is widely used for encryption, both private and public keys are sharing the same modulus.